# show local notification on Windows Flutter

Tags: windows, flutter

Im trying to build a windows application using flutter. I want to show native windows notification on certain events. I did not find any library to do this.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `flutter_local_notifications_linux: ^0.3.0` it part of `flutter_local_notifications` so it should work